# center title on ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I like to center the title on `ExpansionTile`, but couldn't find a way to make the title center. Here is an image of the output screen tested on Web and on android emulator have the same issue. Then I moved to Inkscape to get  better view.

[image]

To make `title` center, I've tried using `tilePadding`, `Row` and adding `SizedBox` on `leading` and `trailing`.

Yes, we create a statfulWidget to have the same facilities, or adding `SizedBox` with `Row`. But I'm really interested to know what and why it is causing this issue, even after wrapping with `Center` and providing  `tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero`, and solution.

**Widget to reproduce the problem**

```dart
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: LSMenu(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

class LSMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ExpansionTile(
        // leading: SizedBox(),
        trailing: SizedBox(),
        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,

        childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        expandedAlignment: Alignment.center,
        expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            "MENU",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        children: [
          MenuItemLS(
              text: "WORK",
              onPress: () {
                print("Work");
              }),
          MenuItemLS(
              text: "ABOUT",
              onPress: () {
                print("About Nav");
              }),
          MenuItemLS(
              text: "CONTACT",
              onPress: () {
                print("Contact Nav");
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MenuItemLS extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function onPress;
  const MenuItemLS({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.onPress,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 4),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => onPress(),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was editing the `expansion_tile.dart` file. Remove this part of the code and you should be able to center it. This only applies to the cached version of the widget I believe. So what you can do is copy the whole file and make it local.
[image]

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Would it be a good idea to change source code? And we are passing widget `SizedBox` should it be taking that width and apply tilePadding.

Comment: Flutter is open source so I don't think that would be a problem. Basically, you just modify a pre-build widget to fit your needs. Remember to make it local and import it on the page that you are using. Totally up to you though. About the SizedBox, since you removed the trailing element, it would not be used anyway, so you can just remove it.